# How to increment variable in angular 2 - 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to increment a variable in angular 2 - 4

When I go from page 1 to page 2 for some reasons this variable (n) is not incremented.

I want every time the page loads the variable n to increment by 1,
after I route 20 times to this page, I want to log 20,

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public n: number = 0; // I want to increment this.


  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.chart_1('500', '100%'));

    console.log('-------- ngAfterViewInit -------');

    let chartwidth1 = $('#curve_chart1').width();
    let chartwidth2 = $('#curve_chart2').width();

    if ( this.n === 0) {
      chartwidth1 += 0;
      chartwidth2 += 0;
    } else {
      chartwidth1 -= 50;
      chartwidth2 -= 50;
    }

    console.log(chartwidth1);
    console.log(chartwidth2);

    console.log(this.n); // 0
    this.n += 1;
    console.log(this.n); // 1

    // google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.chart_1((chartwidth1 - 80), '100%'));

    this.chart_1((chartwidth1 - 80), '100%');
    this.chart_2((chartwidth2 - 80), '100%');

  }



}
```

Comment: for the people who  come here only to downvote, this question don't come here just help if you can, or explain why  you downvote this simple question malakopitoures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have that variable in an injectable service and make that service shared.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
 export class SharedService {
   public n:number;
 }
```

**app module**

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule,
          HttpModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [SharedService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 }) export class AppModule { }
```

**your component**

```
import {SharedService} from 'path of service folder';
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor(private router: Router,private sharedService:SharedService) {
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.sharedService.n +=1;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: you are welcome. I would be happy if it resolves your problem. Don't forget to accept it as answer if it solves your issue. Have a nice day :)